# Putting dynamic CSS URLs in HTTP headers with Fastly CDN

Tags: varnish-vcl, fastly, fastly-vcl

I'm generating dynamic CSS URLs for cache-busting. I.e. they're in the format `styles-thisisthecontenthash123.css`.

I also want to use HTTP Link headers to load the files slightly faster. I.e. have the header `Link: <styles-thisisthecontenthash123.css>; rel=stylesheet`

I'm pretty sure it's possible to do this in Fastly using VCL, but I'm not familiar enough with the ecosystem to figure it out. The CSS URL is in `index.html`, which is cached. I'm thinking I can open `index.html` and maybe use regex to parse out the CSS URL. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to include a `link` header for all requests for `index.html`. You can do that with Fastly, but if the URL for the CSS file is changing you're not going to be able to pull that info out with VCL (you can't inspect the response body).

You could use [edge dictionaries](https://docs.fastly.com/guides/edge-dictionaries/about-edge-dictionaries) and whenever your CSS filename changes, update the reference via the API.

Thing is, if you're going to make an API call whenever the file changes, might as well just keep the filename consistent (`styles.css`) and whenever you publish a new version send a [cache invalidation](https://docs.fastly.com/api/purge) (purge). Fastly will clear the cache in ~150ms, so you then all you have to do is add the header which is can be done in the Fastly web portal with a [condition](https://docs.fastly.com/guides/conditions/using-conditions#sts=Create%20a%20new%20header).